# SQL - I am trying to insert months of a calendar year that are missing from a dataset

Tags: sql, database, subquery, amazon-redshift

The dataset is structured as

```
    id,
    year,
    month 
    )
```

and sample data is as below

```
1, 2020, 01
1, 2020, 02
1, 2020, 11
2, 2020, 01
2, 2020, 02
2, 2020, 03
2, 2021, 01
```

I want to insert the missing months into the dataset per id and year, so the
first

```
1, 2020, 01
1, 2020, 02
1, 2020, 11
```

is missing months

```
1, 2020,04 
1, 2020,05 
1, 2020,06
1, 2020,07 
1, 2020,08
1, 2020,09 and 
1, 2020,12
```

I'm trying to insert these values

I have tried a few queries to check where the month and year are not in the set but am having no luck.

Comment: In your sample, when you give example of the missing months, you omit months 3 and 10. It should be so or it's a mistake? Also, by "missing months" you mean missing months in a year?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake

Comment: Redshift is not postgresql. Please correct the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Generate months for a full year for each `id`, left join with input and take what's empty on the right side of join.

1. **Redshift.** Redshift's `generate_series` doesn't generate dates, and it's leader-node-only function, so can't use it while joining or inserting into tables. But we can generate months with a recursive query instead:

```
-- Generate months between min(year)-01-01 and max(year)-12-01 for each id
with recursive all_months(id, dt, max_dt) as (
  select 
    id, 
    to_date(min(year)::text || '-01', 'YYYY-MM') dt,
    to_date(max(year)::text || '-12', 'YYYY-MM') max_dt
  from test 
  group by id 
  union all 
  select 
    id,
    add_months(dt, 1)::date dt,
    max_dt
  from all_months m
  where dt < max_dt)
-- left join generated months with our data, 
-- and return months for which there's no corresponding joined month
select 
  a.id, 
  extract(year from a.dt) "year", 
  lpad(extract(month from a.dt)::text, 2, '0') "month"
from all_months a
left join test t 
on a.id = t.id and to_date(t.year::text || '-' || t.month::text, 'YYYY-MM') = a.dt
where t.id is null
order by id, year, month
```

2. For Postgres 9.4 and above:

```
    with all_months as (
      select 
        id,
        generate_series(
          make_date(min(year), 1, 1),
          make_date(max(year), 12, 1),
          '1 month'::interval
        )::date dt
      from test
      group by id
    )
    select 
      a.id, 
      extract(year from a.dt) "year", 
      lpad(extract(month from a.dt)::text, 2, '0') "month"
    from all_months a
    left join test t 
    on a.id = t.id and make_date(t.year, t.month::int, 1) = a.dt
    where t.id is null
```

3. For Postgres 9 and up to 9.3:

```
with all_months as (
  select 
    id,
    generate_series(
      to_date(min(year)::text || '-01', 'YYYY-MM'),
      to_date(max(year)::text || '-12', 'YYYY-MM'),
      '1 month'::interval
    )::date dt
  from test
  group by id
)
select 
  a.id, 
  extract(year from a.dt) "year", 
  lpad(extract(month from a.dt)::text, 2, '0') "month"
from all_months a
left join test t 
on a.id = t.id and to_date(t.year::text || '-' || t.month::text, 'YYYY-MM') = a.dt
where t.id is null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.3&fiddle=cdf73e586f834d67d57a39ba4f8733cb)*

Comment: I'm getting this for the make_date function  - function make_date(smallint, integer, integer) does not exist, I'm using redshift so maybe the syntax isnt the same as the standard postgrs

Comment: I added query to work with Postgres older versions - I believe it will work on 9.0-9.3 now. But please consider upgrading your Postgres instance: https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-and-upgrading-methods-costs-risks

Comment: Didn't see the update on DB used.. Updated answer for Redshift. BTW, from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-redshift/info: "Although Redshift to some extent is based on PostgreSQL they are substantially different. Do not add the postgresql tag to questions involving Amazon Redshift"

Comment: Thanks qaziqarta, generate_series() also seems to be only postgres friendly as well, still seeing how this is done in redshift

Comment: @Calibre2010, Edited once more, and now it's actually successfully tested on a real Redshift cluster)